# Ionic2 Tabs swipe back not working swipeBackEnabled

Tags: ionic2, swipe, ionic2-tabs

I am developing an tabbed application I have three tabs

```
<ion-tabs #tabsPage swipeBackEnabled="true">
  <ion-tab [root]="tab1Root" tabTitle="{{'tabs.tab1'|translate}}&zwnj;" tabIcon="ios-home-outline"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab2Root" [rootParams]='filter' tabTitle="{{'tabs.tab2'|translate}}&zwnj;" tabIcon="ios-list-box-outline"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab3Root" tabTitle="{{'tabs.tab3'|translate}}&zwnj;" tabIcon="md-walk"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

Tab 2 is a list view on click each item will push detail page. I was not able to use swipe back in IOS.

When I tried to debug the properties with the below snippet

```
alert(this.navCtrl.canGoBack());
alert(this.navCtrl.canSwipeBack());
alert(this.navCtrl.swipeBackEnabled);
```

I get true, undefined, true

If I set swipeBackEnabled to false
I get true, false, false

Help me here I have tried all combination to enable swipeBackEnabled.

I tried swipeBackEnabled in 
1.module.ts
2.app.html

```
<ion-nav #samNav [root]="rootPage" swipeBackEnabled="true"></ion-nav>
```

3.tabs.html example above

Nothing worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this issue by updating 
"devDependencies": {
        "@ionic/app-scripts": "2.1.4",
        "ionic": "3.9.2",
        "typescript": "2.3.4"
    },

Answer (score 0):

Where did you place the swipeBackEnabled="true"?
I tried it in app.html and the tabs.html but I my output of `console.log(this.navCtrl.canGoBack(), this.navCtrl.canSwipeBack(), this.navCtrl.swipeBackEnabled);` is still `true undefined true`.
My devDependencies are like yours.

```
"devDependencies": {
"@ionic/app-scripts": "^2.1.4",
"ionic": "^3.9.2",
"typescript": "2.3.4"}
```

Comment: I had this in a sub page

Comment: Currently I have not mentioned swipeBackEnabled anywhere in my app. It works fine for me.

Comment: If I don't mention it, canSwipeBack() and swipeBackEnabled() return false